# Unable to select some text from Google Docs with a simple regex

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to highlight some text (in the example below I would like to highlight "ORGANIZA") with some regex on a Google Docs document, but I'm unable to make first work a simple regex to find the "category_name" string.

Why this:

```
function highlightTextTwo() {

  /* DOCUMENT DEFINITION */
  var doc  = DocumentApp.openById('1M6JmJPndLS_hkdaUo5holsdxB5GSSrcWMa1j4Hh7Dig');

  /* VARIABLE DEFINITION */  
  var highlightStyle = {};
  var paras = doc.getParagraphs();
  var textLocation = {};
  var i;

  /* REGEX DEFINITION */  
  var MyRegex = new RegExp('category_name','i');    

  /* COLOR STYLE DEFINITION */
  highlightStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = '#FF0000'; 


  /* CODE */  
  for (i=0; i<paras.length; ++i) {
    Logger.log( paras[i].findText(MyRegex) );
  }


}
```

applied to this document:

```
{
    "map_image": "mapa_con_close_button.png",
    "categories":[
        {
            "category_id": 1,
            "category_name": "ORGANIZA",
            "color": "#4591D0",
            "icon_image": "Organiza.png"
        },
        {
            "category_id": 2,
            "category_name": "DELEGA",
            "color": "#94C5DD",
            "icon_image": "Delega.png"
        },
        {
            "category_id": 3,
            "category_name": "NEGOCIA Y GESTIONA EL CONFLICTO",
            "color": "#E7344A",
            "icon_image": "Negocia_y_Gestiona.png"
        }
```

returns this:

```
[15-06-03 20:12:48:026 CEST] null
[15-06-03 20:12:48:027 CEST] null
[15-06-03 20:12:48:028 CEST] null
[15-06-03 20:12:48:029 CEST] null
[15-06-03 20:12:48:030 CEST] null
[15-06-03 20:12:48:030 CEST] null
```

instead the some nulls and one "category_name".

Comment: You declared the regex well. I guess you need to use it like this: `while (match = MyRegex.exec(paras[i])) { // match[0] will return the found results}`

Comment: I tried this in the Google App Script, but returns nothing:  `while (match = MyRegex.exec(paras[i])) { Logger.log(match[0]); }`

Comment: Try with `paras[i].getText()`. Also, I think you need to use a `g` option in the regexp to find all occurrences: `var MyRegex = new RegExp('category_name','ig');`

Comment: After those two changes I get:
`TypeError: Cannot call method "getText" of null.`

Comment: Ok, you also have `++i`, how many paragraphs have you got? Try with `i++`.

Comment: `Logger.Log( paras.length );` returns 462 paragraphs

Comment: I updated the document with a couple more paragraphs from it, it's too long to put the whole document in here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out a way to display all of your `category_name` strings. Main points:

1. Use RegExp `exec` in a `while` loop instead od `findText`
2. To get all occurrences, we need to use `g` flag with regex
3. To access text in paragraphs, we need `getText()`

Code:

```
var paras = doc.getParagraphs();
var MyRegex = new RegExp('category_name','ig');
for (i=0; i<paras.length; ++i) {
  while (match = MyRegex.exec(paras[i].getText()))
  {
    Logger.log(match[0]); 
  }
}
```

Output in the log:

```
[15-06-04 21:07:36:320 CEST] category_NAME
[15-06-04 21:07:36:322 CEST] category_name
[15-06-04 21:07:36:324 CEST] category_name
```

**EDIT**:

Here is a way to highlight the matches with red color:

```
var paras = doc.getParagraphs();
var MyRegex = new RegExp('category_name','ig');
for (i=0; i<paras.length; ++i) {
    while (match = MyRegex.exec(paras[i].getText()))
    {
        var searchResult = paras[i].findText(match[0]);

         if (searchResult !== null) {
            var thisElement = searchResult.getElement();
            var thisElementText = thisElement.asText();
            thisElementText.setBackgroundColor(searchResult.getStartOffset(), searchResult.getEndOffsetInclusive(),"#FF0000");
        }

    }
  }
```

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly! I'll try myself to highlight the occurrences with an style

Comment: Ok, it works as I stated in the last comment, but I been reading the docs and is not useful for the highlighting that I asked in the question, this returns a text, and for later highlight it it needs to return an object, it has to be with findText it seems. I'm testing some possible solutions and I'll post them if I'm able to make them work.

Comment: Please check my edit, I have tested it and it highlights the words in my test document.

Comment: Perfect!, it works great. Finds and highlights perfectly the regex.